# How to determine the product key from the console for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, license, product-key

On a Surface 3 tablet, how do I determine, from the console, the product key for Windows 10?

Microsoft says:

> Product keys for Windows
>
> A product key is a 25-character code that's used to activate Windows
>   and helps verify that Windows hasn't been used on more PCs than the
>   Microsoft Software License Terms allow. Windows 10: In most cases,
>   Windows 10 activates automatically using a digital license and doesn’t
>   require you to enter a product key. However, if a product key is
>   required, it can usually be found in the confirmation email you
>   received after purchasing Windows, or in the box Windows came in.
>   Microsoft doesn't keep a record of purchased product keys—visit the
>   Microsoft Support site to learn more about activating Windows 10.

Some initial googling suggests:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20200412065627
Username: DESKTOP-9AKB65V\thufir
RunAs User: DESKTOP-9AKB65V\thufir
Configuration Name: 
Machine: DESKTOP-9AKB65V (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18362.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 27096
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.628
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.628
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.628
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is key
PS C:\Users\thufir> winver
PS C:\Users\thufir> wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
OA3xOriginalProductKey
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PS C:\Users\thufir> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\thufir>
C:\Users\thufir>slui.exe

C:\Users\thufir>
C:\Users\thufir>exit
PS C:\Users\thufir> stop-transcript
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20200412065743
**********************
```

firstly, is that above key valid?  Or, rather, how would I determine its validity?

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/7330187/262852

Comment: You cannot. The license is digital and is tied to the hardware.

Comment: yes and no, @music2myear -- but thanks for the link.  Starting from that "key" returned via `wmic path ...` it's of no value?  It cannot be moved to other hardware, recycled or re-used in any way?

Comment: @Thufir - Why exactly are you trying to get the product key.  You don't need the product key in order to reinstall Windows.  So I am trying to understand the reason you require it.  Yes;  It's important to know the reason.

Comment: The only legal way to "reuse" this key is to reinstall Windows on the same hardware, in which case the license will successfully reactivate. This key does not legally exist outside the specific hardware it is already on.

Comment: I'm not a Windows users, @Ramhound but know that keys and licenses can be real pitfalls.  I happen to have this surface 3 and am trying to understand the licensing ins and outs.  see also:  https://superuser.com/q/1541234/55747

Comment: @Thufir - You will never need your product key for Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the key obtained using the `wmic` command you posted to the one obtained from the NirSoft ProduKey utility.  I've used that quite a few times across different systems and found the key it extracts to be good for reinstalling.

If in doubt, use "Control Panel -> Backup and Restore (Windows 7) -> Create a system image" in case you need to do a full restore to your current system state.  It says Windows 7 but it's for Windows 10 too.

Comment: But, legally the key can only be used on the hardware it came with. We cannot recommend illegal actions here on Superuser.

Comment: that's fine.  I suppose I might want to re-install the surface 3; perhaps that key would be of some use there.