# how to copy, persist or save the license key for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, license, pxe, license-key, winpe

Not normally a Windows user, but am considering purchasing a brand new desktop PC with Windows.

Is it even possible to [note](https://superuser.com/q/1541227/55747) a license key for future use with Windows 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the product key from the console for Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1541227/how-to-determine-the-product-key-from-the-console-for-windows-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1241948/windows-10-digital-license-after-pc-format/1241952#1241952

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use Nirsoft's ProduKey utility to extract it.

However, unless it's a "Retail" version license of Windows (i.e. didn't come with the PC and you bought it separately and it's designated as retail and not OEM / System Builder), you're not permitted to move it to another PC, and activation will likely fail.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Also worth noting - many name brand systems have Windows key hardcoded in firmware, so it will automatically find it on reinstall.